# Repeating a GET request without re-running script

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script that will show the bus times from my local stop on a scrollphatHD on raspberry pi zero w. 
I can get the script running and I get the correct bus times, but I am having trouble getting the new bus times without restarting the script.

How can I loop the bus times so that I always get the updated times?

```
import requests
import signal
import scrollphathd
from scrollphathd.fonts import font3x5


r = requests.get("https://skyss.giantleap.no/public/departures?Hours=1&StopIdentifiers=12015491")
dest = r.json()["PassingTimes"][0]["TripDestination"]
avgang = r.json()["PassingTimes"][0]["DisplayTime"]
dest2 = r.json()["PassingTimes"][1]["TripDestination"]
avgang2 = r.json()["PassingTimes"][1]["DisplayTime"]

linje2 = dest + " " + avgang + ",   " + dest2 + " " + avgang2 + ",   "



while True:
     scrollphathd.write_string(str1, y=1, font=font3x5, brightness=0.5)
     scrollphathd.flip(x,y)
     scrollphathd.scroll()    
     scrollphathd.show()
        print(linje2)
```

I want the result to be updated about every 20 seconds or so, but I end up just getting the time from when I start the script over and over.

Comment: "always be updated" How often?

Comment: About every 20 second or so